# Cant store simple array in laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store user ID's in a column in my `User` row, as people can "follow" other people.

So if I am a user, I can follow multiple users. This i want to store in a super simple format, like `[1, 5, 6]` in the database.

The `Following` column is a string format:

```
$table->string('following');
```

I am trying to do this by running the following:

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
$data = $request->all(); 
$follow = $data['follow']; 

if(!empty($user->following)) { 
    $user->following = array_merge($user->following, array($follow)); 
} else { 
    $user->following = array($follow); 
}
```

However it troughs a `Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`

I have done this exactly the same way on another system also build upon laravel, and there everything works like a charm, so I simply dont get why this isn't working. In that database to the other system, the data is stored like mentioned earlier.

I dont want to serialize alot, as this has to be simple, so I can do a

```
$following = User::whereIn('id', $user->following)->get();

foreach($follwing as $follow) {
...
}
```

I dont think this is the best way to do it, however this is the only way I can wrap my head around with my skills. Other suggestions are mostly welcome!

Comment: Why not create another table with two columns: user_id (the one following), and follow_id (the ID of the user that they are following). You can then use a hasMany relationship to get the users that a person is following.

Comment: You can use $table->json('following'); instead of string and store data as json. and json_decode while fetching data. in Laravel 5.3 you can query through json too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not the Laravel way to store data. You should create a new table to store the follower's data.

This can be achieved by creating a [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between user table itself.

Create a `followers_following` table with columns as:

```
id | follower_id | following_id
```

Create two relation function in `User` model as:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers_following', 'following_id', 'follower_id');
}

public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers_following', 'follower_id', 'following_id');
}
```

Then you can query the user as:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->followers;

$user->following;
```

To save the data in DB you can do as:

```
$user->following()->attach($follow);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you want to store array data into the database, the best column type is probably `$table->json('following')`. Coupled with [a cast of that attribute to JSON in your model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), this will let Laravel save/retrieve array data automatically.

That said, you *really* don't want to be doing that for something like follower data. While some database engines can index JSON data, others can't, and storing it as a *string* is even worse. SQL is relational, and user-->follower associations are *relations*.

Instead, you'll want a separate table, something like `user_follows`, that stores the `user_id` and the ID of the user they're following as something like `follow_id`.

Then, use [a many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) to link them:

```
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id');
}

public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your User model define [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators).

```
public function setFollowingAttribute(array $following) {
    $this->attributes['following'] = implode(',', $following);
}
public function getFollowingAttribute(string $following) : array {
    return explode(',', $following);
}
```

Comment: This sort of structure will be essentially un-queryable for OP's use case. Mutators/accessors are the wrong approach to this issue.

Comment: My solution takes into account that OP restricted himself to single string column.

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer to a question is "stop, don't do that".